# Iphone, how can i avoid the watchdog killing my application for taking long time to launch?

Tags: iphone, watchdog

what is the proper way to notify the watchdog that i'm not in an endless loop and that i'm still loading  so don't kill my app?

I'm receiving in my crashlogs 
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
and only when running the app from iphone independently from xcode

the code taking time is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 Reachability* reachability = [Reachability sharedReachability];
 [reachability setHostName:@"www.apps2you.com"];    // set your host name here
 NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability remoteHostStatus];

 if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork||remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork )
 {
  //getting the xml file and then getting the ad images online to display as splah ads.
 }
 else {
//or launch the main interface if there's no connectivity.
  [self DisplayTabbar];
 }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have some initializing that takes a long time then it's best to run it in a new thread (via `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`). Your UI would then start in some "locked" state. Create a method that "unlocks" the UI. As the very last action of your background method, run that unlock method via `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

It's important not to block the main thread so that the run loop can respond to iOS events. That's why you should avoid `sleep` or other blocking stuff. It's alright to block in another thread, though. Also, adapting event-based programming methods help a lot.

**Update:**

Nowadays, it's better to use `dispatch_async` instead of `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`. You still should create a new `NSAutoreleasePool` inside the `dispatch_async` block to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: i'll try that, i'll take the splash screen and put it as main screen, then add indicator view. and run the loading of images in the background like you said, and then coming back at you. Thanks a lot,

Comment: Splash screen is fine, but I'd suggest adding an UIActivityIndicatorView (aka "spinner") to show that something is happening.

Comment: exactly. But i've also noticed something strange i thought you might have encountered it. When i call the perform selector in background. i'm using the 'self' instance. But i'm reading in the console many errors and leaking!?
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x773e360 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
and for other classes NSCFString, NSThread NSHTTPURLResponse...
what do you think?

Comment: Ah yes. You need to set up an autorelease pool in the background method. See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929485/why-is-there-no-autorelease-pool-when-i-do-performselectorinbackground) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441856/iphone-sdk-leaking-memory-with-performselectorinbackground) question.

Comment: thank you for your help, it worked great.
And for more information, to read about threading.
thanks darkdust.

Comment: why is it better to use dispatch_async... I thought the old way is probably cost more writing code, but more close to the CPU with smallest overhead? or wrong?

Comment: `dispatch_async` only starts a new thread (which might be costly) if GCD thinks there is a need to, otherwise it reuses one from its thread pool. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` always creates a new thread. Also, `dispatch_async` is more flexible (you might be able to skip creating a new method which you would've needed for `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`).

Comment: yeah i already knew about the flexibility, but it's new knowledge about the enhanced performance... by using thread pools. 
Thanks a lot man...
I was wondering where you get all your information? do you keep on reading detailed documentations? or you go to apple presentations about the latest stuff?

Comment: I recommend watching the WWDC videos on topics that are interesting to you, you learn a lot of useful stuff there. Apart from that: experience ;-) Ran into problems, tried to solve them, learned stuff on the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think if watchdog is killing your app, then it takes way too long to load and your users wont wait for it. Look at some memory management techniques and you may have to structure your project better.

There may be a way to tell watchdog not to kill your app, but I guarantee your load times will frustrate your users and you won't be getting the out-reach you want with your app.

Comment: iOS is killing your app if the main run loop does not report to iOS within 30 seconds (as far as I recall). It has nothing to do with memory management, it's all about not blocking the main thread.

Comment: open an app and count for 30 seconds, it's a pretty long time to wait when somethings loading. Managing your memory and re-structuring your project WILL free up the main thread and thus make loading considerably quicker. My point is that at current, users aren't going to want to wait 30 seconds for an app, being mobile is about being instant and portable