# Problem while using Multi - threading in iPad programming (for loading large number of images)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, image, ipad, autorelease

i am supposed to load large number of images on to a scrollview which, i suppose would take some time and memory. So, i used a separate thread to load these images in the background. I have used the following multi threading method

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(prepareSliderView) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`

to load the images on a separate thread. While implementing this method i am getting the following messages in my GDB

```
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10647180 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10647300 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10646a00 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10647480 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10646a20 of class UIImage autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I had no clue what this meant as i never executed this method before. So, my questions are

**1 - should i use some autoRelease pool along with this method**

**2 - is there any other way in which i can load large number of images with out putting a lot of load the main thread**

```
-(IBAction)prepareSliderView{
NSLog(@"Preparing slider view");

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int totalPages=[kbDataSource numberOfPagesInBook];
sliderScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-300, self.view.frame.size.width,200 )];
sliderScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(totalPages*150+((totalPages-1)*10), 200); 
sliderScrollView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0];
thumbnailContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, sliderScrollView.contentSize.width, sliderScrollView.contentSize.height)];

newPageSlider.continuous=YES;
newPageSlider.minimumValue=1;
newPageSlider.maximumValue=totalPages;

 thumbnailFrame = CGRectMake(0, 25, 120, 150);
 pageNumFieldFrame = CGRectMake(0, thumbnailFrame.size.height+10, thumbnailFrame.size.width, 50);
for(int i=1;i<totalPages;i++){
    thumbnailView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:thumbnailFrame];
    thumbnailView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *thumbnail = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:thumbnailFrame];
    UILabel *pageNumField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:pageNumFieldFrame];
    pageNumField.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    thumbnail.tag=i+1;
    thumbnailView.tag=i+1;

    id<PageDataSource> pd = [kbDataSource pageAtIndex:i];

    thumbnailFrame = CGRectMake(thumbnailFrame.origin.x+150+10, thumbnailFrame.origin.y, 120, 150);
    pageNumFieldFrame = CGRectMake(pageNumFieldFrame.origin.x+150+10, pageNumFieldFrame.origin.y, thumbnailFrame.size.width, 50);
    [thumbnail setBackgroundImage:[pd thumbnailImageForPageNumber:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pageNumField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d",i];
    pageNumField.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [thumbnailContentView addSubview:thumbnailView];
    [sliderScrollView addSubview:pageNumField];
    [sliderScrollView addSubview:thumbnail];
    [sliderScrollView addSubview:thumbnailView];
    [sliderScrollView bringSubviewToFront:thumbnail];
    [sliderScrollView bringSubviewToFront:pageNumField];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:thumbnail];
    [thumbnailView release];
    [pageNumField release];
    [thumbnail release];
    [thumbnail addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateToPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [pool release];
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each *main* method that you execute in a new thread, either via `NSThread` or via `performsSelectorInBackground:`, you have to create an autorelease pool like this:

```
- (void)myBackgroundOperation
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   // Do some work.

   // At the very end, release the pool.
   [pool release];
}
```

See also: [Why is there no autorelease pool when I do performSelectorInBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929485/why-is-there-no-autorelease-pool-when-i-do-performselectorinbackground)

But for your task I suggest you also look into the [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). See for example the article [Cocoa Tutorial: NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/).

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003746):

> the method aSelector is responsible
>   for setting up an autorelease pool for
>   the newly detached thread and freeing
>   that pool before it exits

So, in your `prepareSliderView` method you need to create and release an autorelease pool:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// some work

[pool release];
```

Comment: hi stephen, in my prepareSliderView() i have created a autorelease pool at the beginning and released it at the end of the method... But still the GDB shows the same output?? did i miss out some thing here??

Comment: How does `prepareSliderView` work? The release statement needs to be at the end of the lifetime of the _thread_ and not necessarily the method. This means that if you use async methods it's going to be a little more complex.

Comment: The prepareSliderView() creates a lot of views, buttons and labels and adds them all to the main scrollview. As the name suggests it creates and make the scroll view ready to be displayed.

Comment: i have added my prepareSliderView() in my question.Kindly have a look at that.

Comment: No, you can't deallocate the pool in dealloc, since dealloc will be run on the main thread. Also, you shouldn't be updating the UI from anything other than the main thread.

Comment: It looks as though you're loading all the thumbnails when the view appears. Can you not just load the images that are visible initially and then go back and add the others later?

Comment: i should do that as it is a good practice... But, here my problem is that, we dont know when the user want to see a particular thumbnail... SO , i am loading all of them at once...

Comment: A `UIScrollView` will tell you when the user moves the view and it will tell you which part of the screen is visible.

Comment: i wil try this and let u know stephen.